# Conversion of Expression with nullable DateTime gives an error

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In a class, I have a static method to fetch the PropertyInfo by supplying an expression.

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expressie)
        {
            MemberExpression me;
            switch (expressie.Body.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
                    var ue = expressie.Body as UnaryExpression;
                    me = ((ue != null) ? ue.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
                    break;
                default:
                    me = expressie.Body as MemberExpression;
                    break;
            }
            if (me == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression does not refer to a property: " + expressie.ToString());
            }

            return (PropertyInfo)me.Member;
        }
```

To make my code more type safe, I changed the expressions that I'm using in part of the methods which make a call to this function.

```
// Old
Expression<Func<T, Object>> expression;

// New (TProp instead of Object)
Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression;
```

As a result, I can't use the old 'GetPropertyInfo' method anymore, because the expression does not match the requested parameters. So I created a new one.

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expressie)
        {
            MemberExpression me;
            switch (expressie.Body.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
                    var ue = expressie.Body as UnaryExpression;
                    me = ((ue != null) ? ue.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
                    break;
                default:
                    me = expressie.Body as MemberExpression;
                    break;
            }
            if (me == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression does not refer to a property: " + expressie.ToString());
            }

            return (PropertyInfo)me.Member;
        }
```

The body of this new expression is exactly the same as the existing one. Because I would like to stick with the DRY principle, I searched for a way to use one method body for both cases. This is possible by first converting the 'Expression<Func<T, TProp>>' into 'Expression<Func<T, Object>>' and passing the converted expression to the 'old' GetPropertyInfo(...) method. I am not able to completely remove the old 'GetPropertyInfo' method, because of other pieces of code still relying on it.

The conversion method that I'm using is the following:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> convertToObjectExpression<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,object>>(
                    Expression.Convert(expression.Body, typeof(object)),
                    expression.Parameters);
        }
```

This works fine, except when I'm using the expression with a nullable DateTime (DateTime?) as type of TProp. In that case the following line results in 'me' being null.

```
me = ((ue != null) ? ue.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
```

Does anybody have any idea what can cause this problem?

I have a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DG735N) that contains the problem.

Comment: In debug mode, can you look at the type of "expressie.Body"? Probably it's not a UnaryExpression.

Comment: how you call this function?

Comment: "when I'm using the expression with a nullable DateTime" - do you mean you use it with a property of a type `DateTime?` or property of a type `DateTime` cast to `DateTime?`.

Comment: @IvanStoev It indeed is a cast from a DateTime property to a DateTime? type in the expression. I need this, because somewhere else I re-use the TProp type to define the type of another parameter and sometimes it must be possible to supply null (actually 'default(DateTime?)').

Comment: @KemalKefeli The expression body is of type UnaryExpression and the cast ('var ue = expressie.Body as UnaryExpression') also does not result into ue being null.

Comment: You have a problem in your design. When calling the new function, you should neither cast nor pass a constant - because it's supposed to return **property**, right. You should really pass the raw property accessor to your new function (which is not possible with the old one because of the `object` cast). You don't even need to share code between the two, the new function body should always be checked for just `MemberExpression` (error otherwise).

Comment: When calling the new function, you can use the syntax that allows you to specify just the first type argument and let the compiler infer the other, like `GetPropertyInfo((TestClass x) => x.DtNullable)` and `GetPropertyInfo((TestClass x) => x.Dt)`

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated the fiddle to use the proposed syntax for passing the expression argument. This still results in the same runtime error. Can you please elaborate on your remark regarding the problem in the design? The retrieval of the propertyInfo is just an example. In my live situation, I have a method with a second parameter which must be of the same type as TProp (added this to the fiddle).

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart And that's the problem - you should always describe/show your real case in order to get the correct help and not waste our time with wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody have any idea what can cause this problem?

The way you called the new function (with `DateTime?` cast from a normal `DateTime` property) and the way you implemented it (via `convertToObjectExpression`) leads to having two `Convert` expressions, hence the problem.

In order to fix it, consider the user *grek40* advice, and/or change the implementation as follows

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expressie)
{
    var body = expressie.Body;
    while (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked)
        body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
    var me = body as MemberExpression;
    var property = me != null ? me.Member as PropertyInfo : null;
    if (property == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression does not refer to a property: " + expressie.ToString());
    }
    return property;
}
```

Comment: This answer solves the actual problem (duplicated convert)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you just go the other way round. Do not relay from your new typesafe method to the old one (with all attached problems), but from the old one to the new method:

```
// relay old interface to new one for compatibility
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expressie)
{
    return GetPropertyInfo<T, object>(expressie);
}

public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expressie)
{ /* your code, as you provided it */ }
```

If you still got problems with this, please provide your calling code

**Edit**

*removed for being irrelevant to the problem*

Comment: I'm going to upvote it anyway, but your last edit really destroyed otherwise a good answer. You don't need a class **instance** in order to get class metadata info (like property).

Comment: @IvanStoev makes sense. I guess I was thinking to much in the way of my own project, where I'm mostly concerned about some lightweight reflection with concrete objects.

Comment: I completely agree with this solution, but I marked @IvanStoev 's answer as the solution, because he actually solves the underlying problem (duplicated convert).

Comment: His answer might indeed be more helpful to others with a similar problem, so thats perfectly fine with me.